# How to Prevent Timeout Function from Running Twice

Tags: javascript, validation, input, timeout

I am trying to automatically pass data from an input field into a function if no new data has been entered after 1000 ms.  However, its behavior is inconsistent and sometimes the function runs twice on a single input.

```
<paper-input id="itemId" on-input="automaticInput"></paper-input>
```

...

```
 automaticInput() {
   let timeout = null;
   let that = this;
   console.log(timeout); // logging each keystroke
   input();
   function input() {
     console.log('input');
     clearTimeout(timeout);
     timeout = setTimeout(function() {
       that.validateInput();
     }, 1000);
   }
 }

validateInput() {
  if (this.$.itemId.value) {
    this.doSomething(); // runs twice
  }
}
```

How do can I properly set the automaticInput function to only run once per input string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a debounce function. Your code is mostly here, just move timeout var out of `automaticInput`:

```
let timeout = null;
automaticInput() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  let that = this;
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    that.validateInput();
  }, 1000);
}
```

Or better create debounce fn like:

```
function debounce(fn, timeout = 0) {
   let timeoutId = null; 
   return (...args) => {
       clearTimeout(timeoutId);
       timeoutId = setTimeout(() => fn(...args), timeout);
   }
}
```

and then you code become:

```
const debouncedValidateInput = debounce(this.validateInput.bind(this), 1000);


<paper-input id="itemId" on-input="debouncedValidateInput"></paper-input>
```

If you use something like `lodash` it already shipped with such helper.

Comment: OK.  I updated the question to reflect your suggestion, but am still having problems.

Comment: It still works as before. For example, you type word "ab". When you press "a" event handler __automaticInput__ is executed and it will create timeout var and will set up a timer for validation function. When you will press "b" new timeout variable will be created and an independent timer will be created. You need to cancel timer from press "a" when you press "b". So timeout var should not be declared within handler function. It should be closured into it.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!